# How to render the timedelta of a Django datetime field vs. now?

Tags: python, django

I do have a Model `Vote` that contains a `DateTimeField` which returns 
 the date in the template like so: `Sept. 22, 2021, 10:02 a.m.`

```
# Model

class Vote(models.Model):

    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I now want to render the time delta between now and the time stored in the Model in the template:

```
# Template

<div> voted {{ vote.created_on|datetime_delta }} ago</div>
```

Should render for example: `voted 16 hours ago` or `voted 3 days ago`

As far as I know there is no built-in solution to this in Django, thus I tried to create an individual template filter:

```
# Template filter

from django import template
import datetime

register = template.Library()

# Output Django:         Sept. 22, 2021, 10:02 a.m.
# Output datetime.now(): 2021-09-22 12:56:57.268152

@register.filter(name='datetime_delta')
def datetime_delta(past_datetime):
    datetime_object = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%bt. %d, %Y, %H:%M %p")
    print(datetime_object) # prints Sept. 22, 2021, 13:20 PM
```

So I somehow tried to create two time objects in the same structure to calculate the time delta but can't make it fit 1:1. Anyways, I don't know if this might be a working approach and neither do I know if there are smarter solutions to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django already has a [**`|naturaltime`** template filter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime). You can use this with:

```
# Template

{% load humanize %}

<div> voted {{ vote.created_on|naturaltime }}</div>
```